# Iterating a select query

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to create a dataset which is a stacked dataset of many select queries with one parameter changed in my where clause.  I am able to do this using python by calling the select query n times and changing my where cause accordingly.  Is this something I can do in SQL in one go without having to make n individual select queries?

For example

```
dfs = []
for name in names:
    dfs.append(spark.select("select * from personal_data where Name = 'f{name}'"))
# Some logic to take the list of dataframes and make one stacked dataframe
```

Is it possible to achieve this with one select query instead of consectuive queries?

The reason the approach currently is as above is because the rows in the table are not grouped together so for example when I enter the where clause for the first name I get rows 1, 6, 10.  The next name would return rows 2, 3, 7.

The resulting dataset should preserve this order i.e.

rows 1, 6, 10, 2, 3, 7.  This at least is why I made many select queries and then stacked the resulting dataframes together.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create multiple DataFrames for that. Just select rows with `Name` in `names` list.

If the list of names isn't too large then you can use `isin` function with `filter`.

```
df.filter(col("Name").isin(*names)).show()
```

Otherwise, use `join` as suggested by @Oliver W.

Comment: Is it possible that this can return rows out of order?  Or would all the rows pertaining to the name predicate appear together and followed by the next lot?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question but this actually returns all the rows that satisfy `Name` is in `names` list. It's equivalent to the SQL syntax `WHERE Name IN ('name1', 'name2', ....)`.

Comment: I added a bit more detail to my question, please let me know if this makes it clearer.

Comment: Ok, just add an orderBy Name and you'll have your rows togther for each Name. (`df.filter(col("Name").isin(*names)).orderBy(col("Name")).show()`)

Answer (score 0):

Use the SQL join:

```py
names_df = spark.createDataFrame([(n,) for n in names],
                                 schema=("name",))
names_df.registerTempTable("names_df")
spark.sql("select * from personal_data as p left join names_df as n where n.name = p.Name").show()
```